# MySQL select query that doesnt have to return a result set

Tags: mysql, select

Say for example I have a login form that takes a username and password and validates it against a database. Usually I would run: `SELECT username, password FROM tablename WHERE username = '$user' and password = '$pass' LIMIT 1;`
This returns a result set for which I have no use. All I wanted to check was if it exists in the database. Is there a MySQL query that can do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tablename WHERE username = '$user' and password = '$pass') whatever_column_alias
```

Returns 1 if exists, 0 if not. It's faster than counting, cause it stops searching further as soon as the subquery hits.

What you select in the subquery doesn't matter. Selecting 1 is just a habit of me.

Answer (score 0):

You can check how many users have that credentials

```
SELECT count(*) as user_count
FROM tablename 
where username = '$user' and password = '$pass'
```

It the result is `0` then the login failed. If `1` it was a success.

Answer (score 0):

Use `COUNT` :

```
SELECT count(*) as nb_user
FROM tablename 
WHERE username ="username"
  AND password = "password"
```